# Check if element is in array, but exclude array's last element?

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if a string is already in array, but during checking exclude last element of that array? By now, I'm using a workaround with `unset()` and re-declaration like this:

```
$fkTableName = $fkTableArr[$colNr0];

unset($fkTableArr[$colNr0]);

if (!in_array($fkTableName, $fkTableArr))
    // do sth

$fkTableArr[$colNr0] = $fkTableName;
```

but it seems pretty redundant to me.

Comment: which array you want to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to slice the array and use it. The below code doesn't include the last element in the array.

```
array_slice($input, -1);
```

So your code becomes:

```
$fkTableName = $fkTableArr[$colNr0];

if (!in_array($fkTableName, array_slice($fkTableArr, -1)))
    // do sth
```

Comment: Good idea, but I'd rather need `array_slice($fkTableArr, 0, -1)` than `array_slice($fkTableArr, -1)`

Comment: The `array_slice($fkTableArr, -1)` implies `array_slice($fkTableArr, 0, -1)`. There's no difference. `:)`

Comment: `array_slice($fkTableArr, 0, -1)` cuts last element, `array_slice($fkTableArr, -1)` leaves nothing, but last element - `var_dump` doesn't lie ;)

Comment: Buddy, If `length` is given and is **negative** then the sequence will stop that many elements from the **end** of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not affect the array, try this:

```
if (in_array($fkTableName, $fkTableArr) && $fkTableName != end($fkTableArr)) {
  // element in array, but not last item
}
```